# How do I configure IDEA to run Perl Scripts or Perl Tests directly from Scratch Files

Tags: perl, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have a fresh installation of IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Community Ed.) on an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (which in turn is a [WSLg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg) guest in a Windows 10 box). (The setup in general does not have a problem - as it seems: IDEA is working fine.) I have installed the [Perl Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7796-perl) from the Marketplace.

When working *inside a Perl project* - with IDEA Project Structure configured appropriate - I can immediately run Perl scripts (.pl) and tests (.t) *from the* respective files' *context menu*. (No customization of the Run Configuration is required - the Run templates work as they are.)

This is not possible, when I add a scratch file (.pl or .t) in the Project Window: The context menu of that file does not contain (any of the) Run menu entries. Also, the buttons (Run ..., Debug... etc.) at the top of the editor window are greyed out, when a scratch file is opened/active in the Editor and the Run configuration is "Current File".

I searched all places I know (which are probably not many): Project Structure and Perl5 language Settings, but found nothing to change this behaviour.

Comparing my IDEA installation on Ubuntu with a native installation on Windows: In IDEA on Windows it is possible to run Scratch files directly.

It is possible to manually edit a Run Configuration for a script upfront: Execution of such a script is working. (Adding only the script path - Output encoding is auto filled with "UTF-8" - to the configuration is sufficient.) But even thereafter: The context menu entries do not show up ...

Your help is very much appreciated, as this feature has a lot of value for me. Thanx in advance.

---

#### Edit(s):

This is my Perl5 Language Setting. Changing to "System Perl" (5.34) does not change anything.
[image: Settings->Lagg.&Fwks.Perl5]

---

Thank you for your feedback(s).

- Didn't file a bug, since installing IDEA inside a WSL guest is not officially supported by Jetbrains. (They have a new, yet experimental, feature - using WSL guests as "remote" runtime for IDEA. This should allow for my Perl code residing on Linux and IDEA residing on Windows - but didn't try this setup ...)
- Continued to use VSCode for Perl development (as I did before): VSCode supports code/runtime on WSL guests natively and has a good Language Server support as well.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. I've tried on my Macbook and on a Linux machine. Add into your question what the `Settings->Langs & Frameworks->Perl 5` screen looks like

Comment: Here you go ... - Nothing customized in the Language Settings - apart from the Perl5 Interpreter and the Target Version.

Comment: I'd report a bug at https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/issues and share [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085).

Comment: Thank you. didn't notice the hint with idea.log immediately. I also regard this as a bug - and thus reached my goal, if I was missing a configuration of IDEA somewhere - see my edit.